# Get only children folders i.e. exclude current folder using glob.glob * pattern search

Tags: python, glob

This is how my directory structure looks like:

```
<ROOT>/
├── root.log
├── a/
│   ├── xyz/
│   ├── a_xyz.log
├── b/
│   ├── xyz/
│   └── b_xyz.log
├── c/
│   ├── xyz/
│   └── d/
│      ├── xyz/
│      └── b_xyz.log
```

And this is the piece of code I am using:

```
dirs_where_there_are_logs = {
  os.path.relpath(os.path.dirname(pth), ROOT)
  for pth in glob.iglob(f"{ROOT}/**/*.log", recursive=True)
}
```

And this is the output, I am getting:

```
{'.', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c/d'}
```

But I don't want the `glob` to include directory in search but only the children directories. This is what the output I need:

```
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'c/d'}
```

Now, now I now I can add `if` condition to ignore the `'.'` output, but I want to know is there anything more pythonic which I can use to achieve this.

Please let me know if there is any.

Edit: Using python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

Use `root_dir` param to specify the root directory for searching:

```
glob.iglob("**/*.log", root_dir=ROOT, recursive=True)
```

Comment: Yes, this will work if I use python 3.10 or higher, but I am using python 3.8. Any other option?

Comment: @TonyMontana, try to pass the file descriptor referring to a directory (root) as `dir_fd` param

Comment: Sorry, it seems `dir_fd` also available from python 3.10 and higher.